# How to reverse the order of tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now i have list of tuples as show below:

```
[(78, -32), (54, -32), (30, -32), (30, -8), (30, 16), (30, 40), (30, 64), (6, 64), (-18, 64), (-42, 64), (-66, 64), (-66, 88), (-90, 88), (-114, 88)]
```

My current codes are as such:

```
i = 13 # Let i start at index 13
tech = [] # Define list
while (x, y) != (start_x, start_y): # while loop to iterate through all the coordinates until the path has been found
    tech.append(solution[x,y]) # Appends the coordinates to tech list
    x, y = solution[x, y] # get x and y coordinates

for i in tech: # Loop thorugh each tuple
    print(i) # Print each tuple
    # time.sleep(1)
    i -= 1  # Decrement the index
```

What i want to do is to print out the list in reverse order starting with the last tuple coordinates at the front and the first tuple coordinates at the back. The problem now is that when i try to decrement the index it throws this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: so `[(-114, 88), (-90, 88)], ...`?

Comment: `i` is not the index, it's the tuple itself.

Comment: @ Ironkey Yes, that is what im looking for

Comment: do print(x[::-1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `i` is the variable you are using to iterate over the `tech` list, so decrementing each tuple by 1 doesn't work, if you want to print the items backwards:

```
print(*reversed(tech),sep="\n")
```

Reverse in-place :-)

```
tech.reverse()
```

Or use a different variable per iteration (Your intent is to decrement `i`?):

```
for x in tech: # Loop thorugh each tuple
    print(x) # Print each tuple
    # time.sleep(1)
    i -= 1  # Decrement the index
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing to accomplish this!

```
x = [(78, -32), (54, -32), (30, -32), (30, -8), (30, 16), (30, 40), (30, 64), (6, 64), (-18, 64), (-42, 64), (-66, 64), (-66, 88), (-90, 88), (-114, 88)]

print(x[::-1])
```

**output**

```
[(-114, 88), (-90, 88), (-66, 88), (-66, 64), (-42, 64), (-18, 64), (6, 64), (30, 64), (30, 40), (30, 16), (30, -8), (30, -32), (54, -32), (78, -32)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.reverse()` function by doing it:

```
data= [(78, -32), (54, -32), (30, -32), (30, -8), (30, 16), (30, 40), (30, 64), 
       (6, 64), (-18, 64), (-42, 64), (-66, 64), (-66, 88), (-90, 88), (-114, 88)]
data.reverse()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(78, -32), (54, -32), (30, -32), (30, -8), (30, 16), (30, 40), (30, 64), (6, 64), (-18, 64), (-42, 64), (-66, 64), (-66, 88), (-90, 88), (-114, 88)]
print(l[::-1])
```

Using `[::-1]` will reverse the list values.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.